# doctrine 2, how to remove many to many associations?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

How do you unlink a relation from a many-to-many table without deleting anything?

I have tried:

```
$getProject = $this->_helper->getDocRepo('Entities\Project')->findOneBy(array('id' => $projectId));
$getCat = $this->_doctrine->getReference('\Entities\Projectcat', $catId);

$getProject->getCategory()->removeElement($getCat);
$this->em->flush();
```

my Projectcat entity:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="\Entities\Projectcat", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $getCategory;
```

Comment: anyone know?  i teied everything.. i can delete the project and it will also delete from the many to many table but this time, i just want to unlink them. i need them to exist but not associated with a category..

Answer (score 13):

A rather old post but wanted to provide a way to ensure the association was removed from the ORM Entity side of doctrine, rather than of having to manually execute each Entity's collection removeElement and to expand on the answer by @Rene Terstegen.

The issue is that Doctrine does not "auto-magically" tie together the associations, you can however update the entity's Add/Remove methods to do so.

https://gist.github.com/Ocramius/3121916

The below example is based on the OP's project/category schema.
It assumes that the table `project_category` is the `ManyToMany` relationship table, and the `project` and `category` tables use the primary key `id`.

```php
class Project
{

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="projects")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(
     *  name="project_category",
     *  joinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="project", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  },
     *  inverseJoinColumns={
     *      @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category", referencedColumnName="id")
     *  }
     * )
     */
    protected $categories;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param Category $category
     */
    public function removeCategory(Category $category)
    {
        if (!$this->categories->contains($category)) {
            return;
        }    
        $this->categories->removeElement($category);
        $category->removeProject($this);
    }
}
```

---

```php
class Category
{    
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Project", mappedBy="categories")
     */
    protected $projects;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->projects = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param Project $project
     */
    public function removeProject(Project $project)
    {
        if (!$this->projects->contains($project)) {
            return;
        }    
        $this->projects->removeElement($project);
        $project->removeCategory($this);
    }
}
```

---

Then all you need to do is to call the `removeCategory` or `removeProject` method, instead of both. The same can be applied for `addCategory` and `addProject` methods as well.

```php
$project = $em->find('Entities\Project', $projectId);
$category = $em->getReference('Entities\Category', $categoryId);
$project->removeCategory($category);
$em->flush();
```

Answer (score 10):

Your information is a bit limited. Some extra information about the database scheme and Project would be nice. But to give it a try.

You have to remove it from both sides of the relationship. You removed it from the category, but you should also remove it from the project.

```
// Remove Category from Project
$Project->Category->removeElement($Category);
// Remove Project from Category
$Category->Project->removeElement($Project);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

An old post, but the answer above helped me, but it may help to expand it a little bit, I have a project that can have many categories (and categories than can have many projects), so this code gets me all of them:

```
$project->getCategories();
```

If I wanted to delete all of the categories for a project, I simply do this:

```
 foreach ($project->getCategories() as $category) {
    $project->getCategories()->removeElement($category);
 }
```

The issue with the original question was that I believe Doctrine wants you to pass in the category that is referenced by the project, not just a reference to the category that you grabbed independently using this code:

```
$getCat = $this->_doctrine->getReference('\Entities\Projectcat', $catId);
```

Hopefully that makes sense. I know I'm messing up the terminology slightly.

Comment: The entity class should not care if the associated entity or reference was used. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies The proxy reference object should be transparent.